# $PATH only shows RVM files-other Path are not shown in Macbook

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, path

When I run `echo $PATH` I always get Ruby or RVM bin files and does not get any of the path I added in my .bash_profile; I am using a MacBook Pro and running Catalina. I am using the default terminal to review my Path .. I checked .bashprofile, .profile and also .bashrc, what could be wrong here?

`echo $PATH` results :

```
/Users/rr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin:/Users/rr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0@global/bin:/Users/rr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMwareFusion.app/Contents/Public:/Users/rr/.rvm/bin

rr@rr-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo $CLASSPATH -- returns null value
```

.Bash_profile :

```
#export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export JAVA_HOME=$PATH:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
export M2_HOME=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1
#export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
#export TOMCAT_HOME=$PATH:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.31
#export PATH=$PATH:$TOMCAT_HOME/bin
#export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/12/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/12/bin
```

Comment: Catalina uses zsh instead of bash as the default interactive shell (for new accounts); zsh doesn't pay any attention to your `~/.bash*` files, it reads `~/.zprofile`, `~/.zshrc`, etc instead. I suspect you need to either switch to bash (see [Apple Support document HT208050: Use zsh as the default shell on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050)) or move your setup commands to `~/.z*` files.

Comment: Which shell are you using (run `echo $SHELL`)?

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps provided in the Apple website on [how to change the shell](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050) and restarted my Terminal app as a Bash shell instead of zsh shell - then I was able to verify the Class path and the PATH Environment variables without any issues